# Problema de autentificaion MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

Resulta que después que hice todos los pasos para contarme a la base de datos, agregar conexiones, hasta ese momento todo iba de maravilla, hasta cuando terminé de agregar mi tablas y su campo , que ejecuto mi programa me sale esto. Yo hice un botón en mi meno que me permite accesar al reporte. cuando le doy al botón me sale este error:

> Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method
>   'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Este es el código de Mi formulario de Reporte:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Consultorio_Clinico
    {
        public partial class ReporteC : Form
        {
            public ReporteC()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            private void ReporteC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'DataSet1.consulta' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
                this.consultaTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.consulta);

                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }

            private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que tienes problemas de seguridad al conectarte a tu base de datos, ahi debes enfocarte, verifica si te puedes conectar a la base de datos desde algun otro sitio.

Comment: Por ejemplo de cuales Otro sitios Te refieres !

Comment: Intenta conectarte a tu base de datos directamente desde toad o alguna otra consola de bases de datos, o revisa alguna otra aplicacion que tengas conectandote a la misma base de datos actualmente y compara las credenciales.

Comment: Nataliel, debes de calmarte. Recuerda que este sitio no trabaja para ti y los usuarios te responderan si tienen el tiempo y la disposicion. Primero verifica que estas asignado la contraseña en el conexion string. Prueba el usuario que estas utilizando si puede acceder por la consola. Intenta creando un nuevo usuario con una contraseña simple e intentalo.

Comment: Ok Lo Intentare :(

Comment: Saludos. En YouTube busca el video **Tip : user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user '** aproximadamente en el minuto 2 con 10 segundos explica que hacer (usando phpMyAdmin).

Answer (score 0):

Este es el formato que deberia seguir una cadena de coneccion a MySql desde .NET :

```
<add name="mySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
```

Comment: Si en My Caso Uno la Siguiente que Tengo que HAcer;

MySqlConnection conectarme = new MySqlConnection("server=localHost;DataBase=consulta_clinica;Uid=root;pwd=root;");

Comment: Solo por probar intenta con todas en minusculas, no deberia causar problemas, pero con MySql no estoy seguro. localHost=localhost, DataBase=database, Uid=uid

Comment: Ok , Otra cosa , Mi formulario del Reporte , lleva por obligación la cadena de caracteres , o se deja como se crea ?

Comment: No te entendí la pregunta, pero usualmente no deberias tener la cadena de caracteres del connectionstring "quemada" dentro del codigo, sino que deberias moverla al archivo de configuracion de la aplicacion.